# How to create bean for each user based on preference

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, javabeans

I have an application where users can use google storage or amazon s3 as a storage medium. 
Users has a preference page and can select the storage medium and configure it ( set access-key for AWS S3 or json-key-file for Google).

I have an interface (DocumentService) which has upload/delete document methods. AmazonS3DocumentService and GoogleStorageDocumentServices are implementing the interface.

I want Spring to manage the beans of documents service; how should I configure beans so that I will have googleService or amazonService created and injected automatically for each user automatically.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe something like request scope beans can work https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the wrong way to go about your problem, holding a object per user will not scale very well.

Have you considered making the services stateless and giving them the information needed upon calling the methods in them?